# Странные символы-квадратики в строке JSON после получения в Tomcat

Tags: java, json, tomcat, jackson

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что может быть за глюк: правильно сконвертированный в JSON обект (проверено вывоводом JSON-строки в консоль в приложении-отправителе) после получения Томкат-сервером искажается: происходит перестановка частей строки в произвольном порядке, а часть символов заменяется странными квадратиками (см. скриншот:)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Причем физически сейчас это происходит в рамках одной машины (Томкат на локалхосте), то есть глюков сети быть не может.

Приложение и томкат запускаются из Интеллиж Идеи. Конертация в JSON – через Jackson 2.9.3. Передача данных – через DoPost.
Кстати, пробовал передавать таким же образом и XML-строку – происходит то же самое.

Причем экспериментальным путем установил, что глюк появляется после превышения определенного объема строки – не слишком большого. В моем случае если в JSON-строке 7782 символа, то все нормально, но при плюс 1 символе начинается квадратик:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Квадратики это символы юникода.

Comment: Вполне возможно, вопрос, почему появляются и как от них избавиться..  )

Comment: Добавьте код который отправляет запрос и код который получает запрос

Comment: а можно привести ссылку на гитхаб? Вот JavaFX приложение: https://github.com/swen922/TimeCountFXProbe2/tree/master/src/com/horovod/timecountfxprobe
 А вот Томкат: https://github.com/swen922/TimeCountServer

Если точно, то вот этот объект сериализуется в JSON: https://github.com/swen922/TimeCountFXProbe2/blob/master/src/com/horovod/timecountfxprobe/serialize/BaseToServerWrapper.java 
затем отправляется вот этим Тридом: https://github.com/swen922/TimeCountFXProbe2/blob/master/src/com/horovod/timecountfxprobe/threads/ThreadSendBaseToServer.java

Comment: ...и в Томкате получается вот этим Сервлетом: https://github.com/swen922/TimeCountServer/blob/master/src/app/ReceiveBaseFromClient.java

Comment: У вас ошибка при чтении данных с InputStream. Браузер использует gzip и поэтому ContentLength не совпадает с фактической длиной данных в теле. Не используйте `req.getContentLength()` а читайте из буфера пока read не вернёт -1

Comment: Добавьте код метода `getInputString` без `logger` в вопрос, я напишу ответ

Comment: Вах, спасибо, Nick! Ваш ответ кажется похожим, обязательно проверю. И вот ссылка на метод getInputStream(). Вижу, что надо изменить строчку в условии цикла while, правильно?  https://pastebin.com/ZvRTSz1T

Answer (score 0):

Огромное спасибо Nick за точную наводку: изменил метод получения данных из входящего потока: убрал "ручной" подсчет длины входящего потока, заменил на BufferedReader. Все заработало. Нутром чуял, что подвох где-то в способе передачи /получения данных где-то "ниже уровня" JVM, но своих знаний о gzip в браузере нет, спасибо, Nick!

Вот новый вариант кода, с ним заработало:

https://pastebin.com/TxENXLbZ